# Magnifying glass geometrical shapes variants

Tags: glass

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnifying_glass

As we see the magnifying glass is a circle.

Can we design & construct magnifying glass with other shapes viz triangle, rectangle, hexagon, Kite ?

Will it effect the magnification of the object which we observe with the magnifying glass after changing the circular shape to different shapes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do some experimentation. That's Physics' primary source of knowledge.

Partly cover a magnifying glass with some opaque material so that the remaining part gets a triangular, rectangular, hexagon, ... shape. Does it still function the way you expect it from a magnifying glass?